# Word for "descending out of control"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I tried my best to dodge trees and rocks as I [...] down the slope.

What's the best fit for the sentence above?

Comment: As I **hurtled** down the slope.

Comment: For clarification- Are you in (e.g. a car) or on something (e.g., a sled, bicycle) or on foot?

Comment: If you are even trying to dodge trees and rocks, is it true to say you are out of control?

Comment: @RoaringFish - You can be under the *illusion* or *delusion* of having control even when you don't actually have any.

Comment: I think this individual descending the slope would realise he had no control when he slammed into the first tree and came to a dead stop, if not before.  People generally know if they have no control. If I am sliding down a 45 degree ice slope, I know I have no control and saying "I tried to dodge stuff" would be a sentence with no truth in it. If I have gone off the road in my car and I am descending a slope, I can - assuming brakes and steering still work - affect the outcome and then "I tried to dodge stuff" makes sense. Assuming people are delusional is quite a stretch.

Comment: @RoaringFish: your actions having effect on the outcome of your ride is not the same as being in control. Being in control assumes you can force the outcome of your ride to be the one that you select. There is a whole multiverse of situations where you are not in control, but your actions still effect the end result. Being _in control_ and dodging trees should result in a safe landing, being _out of control_ and trying to dodge trees may simply effect _which_ tree you hit.

Comment: Is this person in a car, on foot, on a bike etc? Is the character a type of James Bond or a Mr. Bean?

Comment: @oerkelens: why does it have to be a polarised totally in control or totally out of control? If I have, say, 20% control and it is enough to dodge rocks and trees, then I am not *out* of control.

Comment: @RoaringFish: There is no guarantee you will succeed when you _try_ to dodge them - in that situation I would call it _out of control_. I simply disagree that _out of control_ means you have 0 influence anymore, I would just call near-0 influence on the final outcome already _out of control_.

Comment: If you are out of bread, you have no bread at all. If you are out of ideas, you have no ideas at all. If the shop is out of sausages, they have no sausages at all. And if you are out of control, you have no control at all. If you have 20% control you not out of control, you are just not totally in control.

Comment: Not relevant to the example, but similar: "go into tailspin".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried my best to dodge trees and rocks as I ***careened*** down the slope.

> to sway from side to side :  lurch < *a careening carriage being pulled wildly … by a team of runaway horses — J. P. Getty* >  <sub><sup>[-- Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/careen)</sup></sub>
>
> to lurch or swerve while in motion
> <sub><sup>[-- The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/careen)</sup></sub>

Here's almost your exact usage: [Cemetery Murders: A Mystery](http://books.google.com/books?id=m7mwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22as+i+careened+down%22&dq=%22as+i+careened+down%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jWgWVMqXOcqpogSo8YH4Bg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw)

Comment: Or the standard British English version, *careered*.

Answer (score 6):

The possible answers depend on whether the speaker's descent was voluntary. If it was, then *launched myself, threw myself, hurled myself, propelled myself, dived, plunged* and *plummeted* are all viable candidates.

Comment: @medica - Thanks for the upvote. However, the credit belongs to Brasshat, who edited my answer to include *plummeted*.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for a word that describes *descending out of control*, I suggest **hurtled**.

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hurtle):

> **hur·tle** *verb*
>
> *: to move or fall with great speed and force*
>
> *: to cause (something or someone) to move or go with great speed and force*
>
> Examples of **HURTLE**:
>
> - Boulders hurtled down the hill.
> - We kept to the side of the road as cars and trucks hurtled past us.
> - The protesters hurtled bottles at the police.

Also, from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hurtle):

> **hurtle**
>
> *Move or cause to move at a great speed, typically in a wildly uncontrolled manner:*

Comment: *hurtle* doesn't really suggest "out of control" all by itself.  Those cars and trucks hurtling past were probably being driven quite nicely.  Also I think you don't want to hurtle bottles you want to "hurl" them.   Well, I guess I stand corrected, the dictionary does define *hurtle* as *to hurl or fling*- I never used it that way before.

Comment: @Jim - But the verb *isn't* being used all by itself. It's being applied in a context in which there can be no doubt that the speaker has very little control over their own trajectory. Consider also the example usages at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hurtle, which show the verb *hurtle* being used both transitively and intransitively, including in contexts that clearly indicate that the hurtled or hurtling objects are moving uncontrollably.

Answer (score 2):

I tried my best to dodge trees and rocks as I ***tumbled*** down the slope.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tumble) defines tumble as:

> to fall suddenly and helplessly

Note that *[helplessly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helplessly)* means "not able to be controlled" (i.e. "out of control").